# Safari 7 Network Request Timeline doesn't show redirects?

Tags: http, safari

I'm trying to debug an issue with redirects between websites that I'm pretty sure is due to Safari's default handling of 3rd party cookies, but I'm trying to confirm where the issue is by looking at the cookies being passed in requests/responses using the Network Requests timeline in the Web Inspector.  This is all HTTPS traffic, so an external sniffer is out - I need to use Safari's debugging tools.

The problem I'm having is that I think the network timeline is not reporting redirects.  I have a page I've written that contains nothing but a javascript redirect to a vendor website; it *should* validate URL params and pass back a page the performs another redirect.  What I see in the browser is a different page (login page, vendor website).  The network timeline shows my page being loaded, followed by the vendor login page being loaded.  The inspector shows my pages as the referrer to the login page.  There's no reference to this login page in my code - this has to be the result of a redirect from the correct page (the one my javascript code is supposed to redirect to).  But the timeline doesn't show any redirect.

I know it is supposed to show redirects; I found a post on the safari blog when the feature was added to Safari 6.  I can't find a setting or anything to control this.

Is this a known bug?  Was the feature removed in Safari 7?  Or is this operator error?

**Update**: I tested in Firefox, using the "From Visited" option for "Accept third-party Cookies" setting, to mimic what Safari does by default.  In Firefox's timeline, I can clearly see two 302 redirects before landing on the vendor login page.  Safari does not show them.  So it definitely appears that safari is supressing them.  Is this a bug or a setting I've missed?

Comment: Are you certain a redirect is happening? I agree it seems likely, based on what you've described, but can you confirm it in another browser as a sanity check?

Comment: Good point @pieman72.  Due to the suspected cookie issue, I didn't trust that what I saw in another browser would be the same.  But your question made me realize - I could just disable cookies in another browser and compare results.  I've updated the question with my findings.

Comment: Glad that narrows it down a bit. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Safari to get you any closer to an answer. Good luck.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue. Chrome shows 2 requests: GET 301 (Other) -> GET 200 (Document). Safari seems to follow the redirect also but shows only GET 200 (Document).

Comment: Thank you!  The Third Party Cookies setting in Safari pointed us in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Safari the HTTP redirects are shown in the resources tab, not in the timeline. Every redirect is displayed as separate resource entry providing all its meta-information such as timing and headers. Take a look at the screenshot [image]

Selecting a redirect chain entry gives you its status code and the redirect location in the response headers. [image]

Source and more information: https://www.webkit.org/blog/1091/more-web-inspector-updates/#resources_inspection

Comment: The Web Inspector in Safari 9 has been redesigned and I don't see redirections in either the Network, Resources, nor Timeline tabs. This is frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this in case someone stumbles upon this question: In Safari 13, the redirects are shown directly within the network entry.

The title of the network entry is equivalent to the destination after the redirect chain.

[image: Safari network entry]

If you scroll down further, you can see the detailed information about each redirect.

Comment: The worst format of showing redirects IMO! It takes lots of time to find the redirect and connect it to other page request.

Comment: As of today, if the redirects cause an error (Infinite redirection or otherwise), the redirects get flushed and we're unable to see them, even with "preserve logs" checked and even in the Summary URL field of the network request. Writing this March 19th 2024.