# Safari 12 Network Request Timeline not showing redirects

Tags: http, redirect, safari, webkit, safari-web-inspector

It appears Safari 12 isn't showing redirects on the Network Request Timeline. I have tried this on Chrome and I can see it on the Network tab.

There is a similar question posted here that indicates it can be viewed on the Resource tab, but it appears that the answer is no longer relevant as there have been a redesign as pointed out in the answer's comment and it doesn't work there anymore:

[Safari 7 Network Request Timeline doesn't show redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292564/safari-7-network-request-timeline-doesnt-show-redirects)

I have also found a bug report on Webkit which has been marked "RESOLVED FIXED" (closed 2018-10-09 19:50:02 PDT), however, it doesn't seem to be the case:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=150005

The redirect contains a cookie on the response header and I can see that on the request header after the redirect, which is what I expect, but I have no way of knowing where that cookie came from and whether I actually am missing a request-response entry without looking on another browser.

I was thinking that perhaps there's a new settings or maybe a place on where to find it as I haven't been long developing on Safari.

Comment: I am having the same problem in safari 13 dev tools, trying to see why a redirect that authenticates a user is failing, and there is no sign the request ever happened in the network tab, even with preserve log enabled.